# How To check and remove if any subfolder exists in a Folder by Htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a file structure like this.

```
Folder
 - .htaccess
 - Subfolder
    - Otherfolder
      - file1.html
      - file2.html
 - filea.html
 - fileb.html
```

I can have many folders at the place of 'otherfolder' and I don't want to add code for each subfolder of 'Subfolder'.

i want to remove all other subfolders names except folder.

I just want to get URL like - **mywebsite.com/folder/file.html**

## Edit

currently I am using this code snippet in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/([^.]+)\.html$ /folder/$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: The "existing code snippet" doesn't match the file structure you've posted? Perhaps `filea.html` and `fileb.html` should be inside the `subfolder`?

Comment: I've just realised that your "existing code snippet" is also removing the `.html` file extension and the rewrite is assuming extensionless URLs. If this is the case then your desired URL is presumably `/folder/file`, not `/folder/file.html` as you've stated earlier in the question?

Comment: @MrWhite Yeah,,

Answer (score 1):

> I can have many folders at the place of 'otherfolder' and I don't want to add code for each subfolder of 'Subfolder'.

This isn't possible in `.htaccess` alone. The problem is not in removing the subfolder from the URL (although this should already have been done in the internal link), the problem is internally rewriting the request back to the appropriate subfolder. There is no built-in mechanism to "search" for arbitrary files in `.htaccess`.

If you have a limited number of known subfolders then you can do this, but you need to add a rule (in the root `.htaccess` file) for every subfolder. However, this is not particularly efficient since you need to manually test for the existence of that file in each subfolder. You also have a potential problem of name collision. Obviously, if you effectively "flatten" the filesystem the file `file1.html` can only exist once on the filesystem, amongst all subfolders. If there is more than one `file1.html` then the first match wins.

In principle, you would need to do something like the following to rewrite a request for `/folder/<file>.html` back to `/folder/subfolder/otherfolderN/<file>.html`.

```
# Test "subfolder/otherfolder1"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/subfolder/otherfolder1/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/.]\.html$ subfolder/otherfolder1/$0 [L]

# Test "subfolder/otherfolder2"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/subfolder/otherfolder2/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/.]\.html$ subfolder/otherfolder2/$0 [L]

# Test "subfolder/otherfolder3"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/subfolder/otherfolder3/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/.]\.html$ subfolder/otherfolder3/$0 [L]
```

The parent `/folder/` could be abstracted out of the `RewriteCond` *TestString* if you wish, but the `subfolder` and `otherfolderN` would need to be hardcoded. (Although `subfolder` could be manually assigned to an environment variable to save repetition.)

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/subfolder/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$
> RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1.html [L]
> ```

A "problem" with this code is that it rewrites the request regardless of whether the target file exists or not. This is OK if you are rewriting all requests to a single subfolder, but if you have multiple subfolders then you *must* check for the target file's existence before rewriting.

This also rewrites the request even if it already maps to an existing file. So any legitimate files in the `/folder/` directory (eg. `filea.html` and `fileb.html` in your file structure) would not be accessible.

This also rewrites every file type (except for the few file extensions listed in the preceding *condition*). It would, for instance rewrite a request for `foo/bar/file.webp` to `/folder/subfolder/foo/bar/file.webp.html`. If you are only wanting to rewrite `.html` files then include this in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and the preceding *condition* is not required.